# Is it possible to declare different stack size for different process in SimGrid

Tags: simgrid

I can define a stack size of `msg_process_t` by flag `--cfg=contexts/stack-size=10` at the beginning of simulation.

But is it possible to define a different stack size for different processes, because at most my processes use small size of stack, but a master process needs a lot more kilobytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is currently not implemented. This bug requests it:
https://gforge.inria.fr/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=18137&group_id=12&atid=165